# C Language: Why do dynamically-allocated objects return a pointer, while statically-allocated objects give you a choice?

Tags: c, malloc

This is actually a much more concise, much more clear question than the one I had asked here before(for any who cares): [C Language: Why does malloc() return a pointer, and not the value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759023/c-language-why-does-malloc-return-a-pointer-and-not-the-value) (Sorry for those who initially think I'm spamming... I hope it's not construed as the same question since I think the way I phrased it there made it unintentionally misleading)

-> Basically what I'm trying to ask is: Why does a C programmer need a pointer to a dynamically-allocated variable/object? (whatever the difference is between variable/object...)

If a C programmer has the option of creating just 'int x' or just 'int *x' (both statically allocated), then why can't he also have the option to JUST initialize his dynamically-allocated variable/object as a variable (and NOT returning a pointer through malloc())?

*If there are some obscure ways to do what I explained above, then, well, why does malloc() seem the way that most textbooks go about dynamic-allocation?

Comment: Dynamic means at run-time. How can we have a pointer pointing to resource acquired at run-time during compile time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Note: in the following, `byte` refers to `sizeof(char)`*

Well, for one, `malloc` returns a `void *`. It simply *can't* return a value: that wouldn't be feasible with C's lack of generics. In C, the compiler must know the size of every object at compile time; since the size of the memory being allocated will not be known until run time, then a type that could represent any value must be returned. Since `void *` can represent any pointer, it is the best choice.

`malloc` also cannot initialize the block: it has no knowledge of what's being allocated. This is in contrast with C++'s `operator new`, which does both the allocation and the initialization, as well as being type safe (it still returns a pointer instead of a reference, probably for historical reasons).

Also, `malloc` allocates a block of memory of a specific size, then returns a pointer to that memory (that's what `malloc` stands for: *memory allocation*). You're getting a pointer because that's what you get: an unitialized block of raw memory. When you do, say, `malloc(sizeof(int))`, you're not creating a `int`, you're allocating `sizeof(int)` bytes and getting the address of those bytes. You can then decide to use that block as an `int`, but you could also technically use that as an array of `sizeof(int)` `char`s.

The various alternatives (`calloc`, `realloc`) work roughly the same way (`calloc` is easier to use when dealing with arrays, and zero-fills the data, while `realloc` is useful when you need to resize a block of memory).

Comment: This is false: "Because all pointer types have the same size"

Comment: @R.. Really? I thought they were. Could you explain?

Comment: `void *` (which has the same representation as `char *`) is capable of representing any pointer, but other pointers can be smaller. For instance if memory space is 256k and integers are 4-byte, `int *` could be 16-bit while `char *` and `void *` would have to be larger. And of course representations need not be equivalent. It's also possible that a sophisticated/bloated (depending on your perspective) implementation could encode some bounds information in pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you create an integer array in a function and want to return it.  Said array is a local variable to the function.  You can't return a pointer to a local variable.

However, if you use malloc, you create an object on the heap whose scope exceeds the function body. You can return a pointer to that. You just have to destroy it later or you will have a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

It's because objects allocated with `malloc()` don't have names, so the only way to reference that object in code is to use a pointer to it.

When you say `int x;`, that creates an object with the name `x`, and it is referenceable through that name.  When I want to set `x` to `10`, I can just use `x = 10;`.

I can *also* set a pointer variable to point to that object with `int *p = &x;`, and then I can alternatively set the value of `x` using `*p = 10;`.  Note that this time we can talk about `x` without specifically naming it (beyond the point where we acquire the reference to it).

When I say `malloc(sizeof(int))`, that creates an object that *has no name*.  I cannot directly set the value of that object by name, since it just doesn't have one.  However, I *can* set it by using a pointer variable that points at it, since that method doesn't require naming the object: `int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));` followed by `*p = 10;`.

You might now ask: *"So, why can't I tell malloc to give the object a name?"* - something like `malloc(sizeof(int), "x")`.  The answer to this is twofold:

- Firstly, C just doesn't allow variable names to be introduced at runtime.  It's just a basic restriction of the language;
- Secondly, given the first restriction the name would have to be fixed at compile-time: if this is the case, C already has syntax that does what you want: `int x;`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you misunderstand the difference between declaring 'int x' and 'int *x'. The first allocates storage for an int value; the second doesn't - it just allocates storage for the pointer.

If you were to "dynamically allocate" a variable, there would be no point in the dynamic allocation anyway (unless you then took its address, which would of course yield a pointer) - you may as well declare it statically. Think about how the code would look - why would you bother with:

```
int x = malloc(sizeof(int)); *x = 0;
```

When you can just do:

```
int x = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about things wrong.  It is not that int x is statically allocated and malloc(sizeof(int)) is dynamic.  Both are allocated dynamically.  That is, they are both allocated at execution time.  There is no space reserved for them at the time you compile.  The size may be static in one case and dynamic in the other, but the allocation is always dynamic.

Rather, it is that int x allocates the memory on the stack and malloc(sizeof(int)) allocates the memory on the heap.  Memory on the heap requires that you have a pointer in order to access it.  Memory on the stack can be referenced directly or with a pointer.  Usually you do it directly, but sometimes you want to iterate over it with pointer arithmetic or pass it to a function that needs a pointer to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Everything works using pointers. "int x" is just a convenience - someone, somewhere got tired of juggling memory addresses and that's how programming languages with human-readable variable names were born.
2. Dynamic allocation is... dynamic. You don't have to know how much space you are going to need when the program runs - before the program runs. You choose when to do it and when to undo it. It may fail. It's hard to handle all this using the simple syntax of static allocation.
3. C was designed with simplicity in mind and compiler simplicity is a part of this. That's why you're exposed to the quirks of the underlying implementations. All systems have storage for statically-sized, local, temporary variables (registers, stack); this is what static allocation uses. Most systems have storage for dynamic, custom-lifetime objects and system calls to manage them; this is what dynamic allocation uses and exposes.

There is a way to do what you're asking and it's called C++. There, "`MyInt x = 42;`" is a function call or two.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question comes down to this:

> If a C programmer has the option of creating just `int x` or just `int *x` (both statically allocated)

The first statement allocates memory for an integer. Depending upon the placement of the statement, it might allocate the memory on the stack of a currently executing function or it might allocate memory in the `.data` or `.bss` sections of the program (if it is a global variable or `static` variable, at either file scope or function scope).

The second statement allocates memory for a pointer to an integer -- it hasn't actually allocated memory for the integer itself. If you tried to assign a value using the pointer `*x=1`, you would either receive a very quick `SIGSEGV` segmentation violation *or* corrupt some random piece of memory. C doesn't pre-zero memory allocated on the stack:

```
$ cat stack.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int *l;
    int *m;
    int *n;
    printf("i: %d\n", i);
    printf("j: %d\n", j);
    printf("k: %d\n", k);
    printf("l: %p\n", l);
    printf("m: %p\n", m);
    printf("n: %p\n", n);
    return 0;
}
$ make stack
cc     stack.c   -o stack
$ ./stack
i: 0
j: 0
k: 32767
l: 0x400410
m: (nil)
n: 0x4005a0
```

`l` and `n` point to something in memory -- but those values are just garbage, and probably don't belong to the address space of the executable. If we store anything into those pointers, the program would probably die. It might corrupt unrelated structures, though, if they are mapped into the program's address space.

`m` at least is a `NULL` pointer -- if you tried to write to it, the program would certainly die on modern hardware.

None of those three pointers actually *point* to an integer yet. The memory for those integers doesn't exist. The memory for the pointers *does* exist -- and is initially filled with garbage values, in this case.

The [Wikipedia article on L-values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29) -- mostly too obtuse to fully recommend -- makes one point that represented a pretty significant hurdle for me when I was first learning C: *In languages with assignable variables it becomes necessary to distinguish between the R-value (or contents) and the L-value (or location) of a variable.*

For example, you can write:

```
int a;
a = 3;
```

This stores the integer value `3` into whatever memory was allocated to store the contents of variable `a`.

If you later write:

```
int b;
b = a;
```

This takes the *value stored in the memory referenced by `a`* and stores it into the memory location allocated for `b`.

The same operations with pointers might look like this:

```
int *ap;
ap=malloc(sizeof int);
*ap=3;
```

The first `ap=` assignment stores a *memory location* into the `ap` pointer. Now `ap` actually points at some memory. The second assignment, `*ap=`, stores a value *into that memory location*. It doesn't update the `ap` pointer at all; it reads the value stored in the variable named `ap` to find the memory location for the assignment.

When you later use the pointer, you can choose which of the two values associated with the pointer to use: either the actual contents of the pointer *or* the value pointed to by the pointer:

```
int *bp;
bp = ap; /* bp points to the same memory cell as ap */

int *bp;
bp = malloc(sizeof int);
*bp = *ap; /* bp points to new memory and we copy
              the value pointed to by ap into the
              memory pointed to by bp */
```

I found assembly far easier than C for years because I found the difference between `foo = malloc();` and `*foo = value;` confusing. I hope I found what was confusing you and *seriously* hope I didn't make it worse.